# Can't get inventory update script to work

Tags: php, opencart

I wrote this script that allows me to update inventory in my OpenCart site. The CSV we use for this update is 64k rows and counting.

I use it on two different sites and the script/CSV combo works great on the one site but I cannot get it to update the database in the other site.

I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work. The credentials are correct the queries are correct. When I run the script I dont get any errors. I'm 100% stumped at this point

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","db_user","db_password", "db_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$i = '1';

//Gets CSV from a different domain
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('inventory.csv'));
$count = count($csv);

$sql  = '';

while ($i < $count) {
if($csv[$i][1] != '') {
    echo $csv[$i][1].'<br />';
    echo $csv[$i][3].'<br />';
    $sql .= "UPDATE product SET quantity = '" . $csv[$i][3] . "' WHERE isbn = '" . $csv[$i][1] . "';\n";
}
$i++;
}

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);

echo '<font size="5" color="red"><b>Inventory Update is Complete!</b></font>';
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: why would you expect errors? You have absolutely no error handling code on the main db call at all. You simply assume success. And retrieving individual errors from a `multi_query` is a serious pain the rump. YOu really would be better off ditching the entire array_map business, and use a conventional `while($row = fgetcsv(...) { ... do single query ... check for errors...}` loop

Comment: oh, and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well...

Comment: I did it one query at a time but given that we have so many rows the script gets quite heavy and it gives me trouble.

Comment: When you run the script does the `Inventory Update is Complete!` message appear?

Comment: Yes it does. The script seems to run with no issues but simply put the database does not update. Effen weird.